Avatars and humans
Can someone explain the internal human conflict of an avatar when it is reincarnated into a human being and the physical and emotional effect on that same human?

@TomRichards According to Shri Madhvacharya, the incarnations of Shri Vishnu (i.e. God) are perfect and complete. They experience no conflict and pain but only display human-like behavior to teach people how to execute and protect righteousness or to delude demonic souls so that they can think God is not God and go to eternal hell. Eternal hell is called Andhatamas (Andha = blinding and tamas = darkness).

@TomRichards Demonic souls intrinsically prefer to hate the Supreme Being Lord Vishnu and they thrive in an environment that reinforces their perverse hatred and jealousy. Since hatred and jealousy can only be reinforced by tremendous pain and agony, these demonic souls thrive in a very painful environment and thus their intrinsic natures are in consonance with their surroundings. Since the Supreme Lord Vishnu is free from any defects and is an embodiment of perfect justice, He provides these demonic souls a means to reach their intrinsically preferred state, which is eternal hell (Andhatamas)

@Tom Richards Andhatamas, or eternal hell, is very different from the temporary hells. The pain in the latter hells is there to punish soul for their sins so that they can redeem themselves and go to their next births. Since (finite duration of sins = finite time for punishment) souls don't stay forever in these hells. Andhatamas, however, is not a place of punishment but a final destination. Although the pain experienced in Andhatamas is much greater than the pain in the temporary hells, Andhatamas is place filled with activity .... and extreme pain, hatred, and jealousy towards Lord Vishnu.

Since Lankāpati Rāvanā's boon from Brahmā (creator God) left out humans and animals, Bhagavān Vishnu took avatāra as human and so, He behaved as human throughout that avatāra. But in Krishnāvatāra, there was no such restriction. So, depends upon the purpose of avatāra, particular human qualities will be revealed.
